# DateTimePicker as a Parameter for ReportViewer

Tags: c#, ms-access

I would like my button to search for a specific date in the ReportViewer where it will display a specific date of the data.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataReport.DataTable1 + dateTimePicker2.Value());

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

This is the Query I used in the DataAdapter.

```
SELECT       Customer.CID, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, Booking.VehicleNumber, Customer.MemberType, Customer.Points, Booking.[Time], Booking.[Date]
FROM        (Booking INNER JOIN
             Customer ON Booking.CID = Customer.CID)
WHERE        Booking.[Date] = (dateTimePicker2)
```

My code above, under the button shows that "dateTimePicker2.Value" won't work with. I've tried using it as a text, but it still shows error. What should I convert it to, or should I add in a string?

Comment: Have your tired wrapping dateTimePicker2.Value in quotes so it represents a String?

Comment: Let me try quoting it.

Comment: `this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataReport.DataTable1,"dateTimePicker2".Value());` something like this?

Comment: this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataReport.DataTable1,dateTimePicker2.V‌​alue().ToString());

Comment: Uhm, it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a parameter in the DataAdapter for the date. This is assuming System.Data.OleDb is being used.

```
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"
    SELECT  Customer.CID, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, Booking.VehicleNumber, Customer.MemberType, Customer.Points, Booking.[Time], Booking.[Date]
    FROM    (Booking INNER JOIN
            Customer ON Booking.CID = Customer.CID)
    WHERE   Booking.[Date] = @booking_date");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@booking_date", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
DataTable1TableAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
//{...}
this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataReport.DataTable1);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```